# Class not found com.cisco.sdp.vsn.node.channel.tcp.handler.sftp.TestSftpServerHandlerIntegration

Tags: java, classpath, classnotfoundexception

```
Class not found com.cisco.sdp.vsn.node.channel.tcp.handler.sftp.TestSftpServerHandlerIntegration
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cisco.sdp.vsn.node.channel.tcp.handler.sftp.TestSftpServerHandlerIntegration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:685)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

---

```
import com.cisco.sdp.junitrunner.SDPJunitMethodOrderTestRunner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

/**
 * @author anghatak
 * 
 */
@RunWith(SDPJunitMethodOrderTestRunner.class)

public class TestSftpServerHandlerIntegration extends
    IntegrationTestingEnvironmentSetup {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory
    .getLog(TestSftpServerHandlerIntegration.class);

public static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private static com.jcraft.jsch.Session session;
private static SshServer sshd;

/**
 * Initilize
 */
@BeforeClass
}
```

while I am running this class it says like this how we can resolve this

Comment: Isn't *class not found* a pretty clear error message?

Comment: What is the package that contains your test class?

Comment: package com.cisco.sdp.vsn.node.channel.tcp.handler.sftp;  and class name TestSftpServerHandlerIntegration.java sir but class is present in my project why this error is coming and

Comment: recompile the class,if it is a maven project ,just update it.

Comment: i have recompiled but still is there